How to get rid of weird curve with glass
I've had this issue before where the problem turned out to be that I was using a plane with no thickness as the glass. This time, however, the plane with no thickness looked fine and now I've added a thin thickness to it (smaller than a centimeter like real glass panes), it's doing this. Anyone know how to help?


First thought:  try a real environment in there to test with, don't try to guess at what it should look like inside an infinite void (the only reflection in this case may be the light itself).  Second: if this is going to hang you up forever, settle for physically plausible instead of physically accurate for this project.

This may be happening because of smooth shading on the cuboid pane of glass, causing the normals to bend into more of an ellipsoid shape. Because the normals effect refraction, it looks like a curved lens. Shade the glass plane as flat instead.
